# Higher-level socket functions

Tags: c#

I have a typical network protocol consisting of typical message stream (32-bit length field + variable-length body) and I want to read messages asynchronously from a TCP socket.

However C# seems to provide a rather low-level API: I still have to allocate buffers, track the written offset and data length by hand, and maintain state between separate calls to read length and body like in the bad old days of C.

Are there any higher-level functions that I can try out before diving into writing tedious asynchronous stateful code? (no third-party libraries).

Comment: You can set the sockets to non-blocking which spares you the multi-threading. But even then it's rather annoying to code. I'm working on a bit of RPC on top of protobuf.net and thus similar problems with buffering and packetizing.

Comment: Actually a very interesting question. I've handcoded stuff like this so many times, and at no time I stopped to think if there were a lib or .Net api for this kind of situation. Guess I tunnel visioned :)

Comment: @CodeInChaos you'll have to let me know what you would prefer there...

Comment: @Marc I don't understand what you want to say

Comment: @CodeInChaos - well, what could I expose to make that less annoying? Maybe an event/callback approach like SAX?

Comment: @Marc The annoyances I was talking about were mainly related to buffering and sockets. i.e. very similar to the OPs problems.I haven't written the protobuf deserialization/method invokation part, so I don't know how well that will work out.

Comment: A pretty close question to; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056768/tcp-ip-library-framework-for-c-sharp

Comment: There is nothing "typical" in what you've requested. It is your own protocol, so you have to implement it - all by yourself. Only you can know where one message ends and another begins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing built-in, no. In fact I can't think of any 3rd party libs for this either. I haven't tried, but it *occurs* that C# 5 may offer some language-level shiny here. The other option is to use a separate thread that reads synchronously, but that then uses a thread instead of IO completion ports.