# TCP/IP library (framework) for C#

Tags: c#, .net, client-server, tcp

Is there any asynchronous library for working with TCP/IP on C#?

Comment: What's wrong with System.Net / System.Net.Sockets?  What extra do you want the library to offer on top of that?

Comment: inconvenient to work. Especially with the use of asynchronous methods

Comment: I developed two of them, first one is using the BeginXXX/EndXXX pattern, second one uses the XXXAsync pattern (high performance sockets, introduced with .NET 3.5, available for .NET 2.0 SP1 & 3.0 SP1). Do you need any guidance to develop your own or you are interested stricly in just using one?

Comment: i'm interested in using one. Well, where can i find docs about development of this thing?

Comment: The async patterns in the BCL are pretty consistently implemented I find.  If there is a different pattern you have in mind then searching on that - or explaining it here might turn something else up.  But TCP/IP is by its very nature low level and therefore somewhat 'inconvenient'... if you wrap it up in lots of convenience you've no longer got TCP.  Maybe you actually want a higher level protocol such as those offered by WCF?

Comment: How do you imagine you could use a “convenient” library? What exactly do you find inconvenient about the libraries provided with the Framework?

Comment: I work with not stable lines. TCP is needed. BCL - what is this?

Comment: BCL = Base Class Libraries... Have you looked at WCF then? You can still use TCP as the underlying protocol but everything is managed for you.  You have a choice - go low level and get your hands dirty and deal with all the inconvenience, or go high level lose some control.  No point in reinventing the wheel IMHO.

Comment: An example, when you work with System.Net.Sockets with asynch methods, you need use BeginAccept EndAccept and others. No so many documentation about this. So I find library.

Answer (score 3):

.NET has [`System.Net.Sockets`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) - did you check this out ?

Comment: scarcely. I need simple work. I don't want think about synchronization. System.Net.Sockets is primitive

Comment: Primitive requirements need primitive tools. Perhaps you could explain what you wish to achieve at the higher level for which you find System.Net.Sockets unsuitable?

Comment: An example, when you work with System.Net.Sockets with asynch methods, you need use BeginAccept EndAccept and others. No so many documentation about this. So I find library.

Comment: did you click on the link in my answer ? there is tons of documentation from MS...